# Where can I farm Synthetic in The Following?

Tags: dying-light, dying-light-the-following

I've been replaying Dying Light: The Following in anticipation for the release of Dying Light 2, and in doing so I've been trying to complete as much content in the DLC as possible. Fully upgrading your character's Buggy in the game requires the uncommon crafting material "Synthetic", to be used in Experimental Military Buggy Parts.

As far as I can tell, Synthetic can often be found when searching military vehicles, and rarely found when searching semi trucks. I've not discovered an area with more than three military jeeps, and searching the semi trucks seems too inefficient to be a viable location for it.

Are there any military checkpoints that have more than three jeeps to be looted, or are there two checkpoints far enough apart that I can bounce between the locations and allow the military loot to respawn?

Where is the best place in The Following for me to farm Synthetic?